# elantech touchpad PS/2 multitouch not working in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch, elantech

i brought new hp pavallion ab-104tx which has elantech touchpad PS/2 . Touchpad multitouch features like double scrolling was working fine in windows 10, then i dual booted my laptop with ubuntu 14.04 ,and in it my touch pad multitouch features stop working .It's working normally still in window but not in ubuntu , in it only left click right click and single finger touch are working.

Comment: This might be helpful in your case: http://askubuntu.com/questions/626612/touchpad-issues-elantech-ps-2

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade the kernel buy running

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
```

and reboot.

Comment: i tried it but it doesn't work  @Pilot6 gave me error in last after installation

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: Please do not post outputs to comments. Edit your question.

Comment: i tried your command and installed it as you said but my touchpad doesn't start working.

Comment: Try more recent mainline kernels.

Comment: It starts working few days before suddenly after updating , upgrading and rebooting .